# What is the maximum number of pseudo-random numbers that can be generated with numpy.random before the sequence begins to repeat?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-random

I need to generate many hundreds of millions of random numbers for a clustering analysis. I am using numpy.random and was wondering if anyone knows the maximum number of pseudo-randoms that can be generated with numpy.random before the sequence begins to repeat? A quick look in the numpy documentation didn't help.

I know I can generate numbers in chunks using different seeds, but I'm curious as to the maximum number.

Comment: Do you need _unique_ random numbers ?

Comment: `numpy.random` provides many functions.  What does your actual RNG look like.

Comment: What kind of errors are significant for your clustering analysis?

Comment: @PatrickArtner -- yes, I need all numbers to be unique. No repeats.

Comment: @wim -- I'm not sure what you mean. I was simply using the default numpy.random.rand(N) set-up. Is that

Comment: " I need all numbers to be unique. " - then simply relying on a random number sequence will not be sufficient.

Comment: @MitchWheat -- so what would you recommend?

Comment: @aim If you want all numbers to be unique, then the answer is pretty much independent on actual RNG used - f.e. it would be 2^64 max for 64bit numbers produced and used, and then, obviously one of the previously sampled number will be repeated. If we're talking about whole SEQUENCE of random numbers, then it would be what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thanks all -- very helpful and informative answers/comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, I believe, Mersenne Twister with period 2<sup>19937</sup>-1

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.set_state.html